# Product List Attribute Filter Query

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, performance

I have added one filter in Method `_getProductCollection()`  of the class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`  as follows.

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
     ...
    $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();
    $this->_productCollection->getSelect()->joinInner(
        array('cpe' => 'catalog_product_entity'),
        'e.entity_id = cpe.entity_id'
    ) 
    ->where("cpe.type_id = 'simple'"); 
    ...
}
```

The above code is working fine as of Magento Version 1.7. But whenever I write the following code, it gives

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.type_id' in 'where clause'

error.

The code (which is not working).

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
     ...
    $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();
    $this->_productCollection
        ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','simple');
    ...
}
```

Now the **Questions**.

1. Will there be any performance impact if I use the first working
   code?
2. is there any other way to get around to having a proper product
   filter?

**UPDATE:**

Whenever I apply the following code and use `rwd` theme, I am not getting any error. But whenever I use the `default` theme, I get the below error,

**Code**

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
     ...
    $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();
    $this->_productCollection
         ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id')
         ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','simple');
    ...
}
```

**Error**

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.type_id' in
> 'where clause', query was: SELECT FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2))
> / 10) + 1 AS `range`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM
> `catalog_product_index_price` AS `e`  INNER JOIN
> `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON
> cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND
> cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '3' WHERE
> (`e`.`type_id` IN('simple')) AND ( e.website_id = '1' ) AND (
> e.customer_group_id = 0) AND (e.min_price IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY
> FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 10) + 1 ORDER BY
> FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 10) + 1 ASC

Comment: which magento version  u have use?? *& have applied magento  patches

Comment: wtf? now has sense... i was trying over a EE 1.14 on RWD, that is just unacceptable, how can a view theme change an entire query even worst how can change the main table... this couldn't be anything but a bug. Well done @Magento Learner!

Comment: Exactly, the view theme creates problem. thanks. The code should be independent of a theme

Answer (score 0):

I think that:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple');
```

Should works, you don't need to add `type_id` to `select` since is a `catalog_product_entity` column and it's retrieved by default. I always suggest logging the final query in order to get the best idea of what is happening:

```
Mage.:log($collection->getSelectSql(true));
```

BTW: The first code block has no sense at all since you are joining the main table *(`catalog_product_entity`)* to itself.

Comment: " in Magento 1.7 they did an optimization on the select sql that is used for the price filtering options. They remove the FROM sql part (which is product entity - which contains type_id attribute) and make the price_index related table the main one - the one that is used in the FROM part of the query. So basically the table from which the data is selected is not the product entity table anymore (you lose all products base attributes) the main table becomes the product index. This is an core update that the Magento team added starting 1.7 versions." Refer the following

Comment: http://sohu.io/questions/886200/can-not-load-and-filter-using-type-id-on-a-product-collection

Comment: wooow my fault folk, for some reason, i was thinking in backend block getCollection method, so in this scenario your first code it's ok I'm not sure if it is the best solution but seems to be ok. Sorry

Comment: @MagentoLearner are you sure about that post? i've just re-checked on a EE1.14 i have installed and still using catalog_product_entity as main table, except when you set to use flat catalog (absolutely recommended) but in both cases you have type_id present in the select. Can you log the query as i've wrote in the original Answer?

Comment: Yes I am sure about that. And read that from some other forum also

Comment: mmmm interesting... i Also check the query in a search case and is using catalog_product_entity as main table, maybe the "magento team" have decided to rollback that changes. I can't found any 1.7 installed to check it but the idea of change the main table of an entity sounds like a very bad architectural decision...  Well note that you just ruined my weekend, now i need to find and install a CE1.7 and look this crap with my own eyes... my wife will not be happy with this :)

Comment: :).  but check for <=CE1.7 as described in the forum.

Comment: Before means in CE1.6 the simple `AddAtrributeToFilter` seemed to be working well.

Comment: Ok i will take a look at CE1.6 so, thanks!

Comment: Have you checked my updates on this?