# Magento 1.9.2 addAttributeToFilter function not working default theme

Tags: magento-1.9, filter

I have added product filter addAttributeToFilter in Catalog/Block/Product/List.php file as show below

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract {

    ...

    protected function _getProductCollection() {
        ...
        $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'));
        ...
        return $this->_productCollection;
    }

    ...

}
```

The above code is not working in **default magento theme** but same is working on **RWD Magento theme**.

**Now query :**

1. How it will solve?
2. Is Magento developed code base on theme?

**Update :**

```
 $this->_productCollection->getSelect()->joinInner(array('cpe' => 'catalog_product_entity'),'e.entity_id = cpe.entity_id') 
              ->where("cpe.type_id = 'simple'");
```

This is working in all theme.

Comment: #2 Sadly yes seems to be exactly that way... if you are using/extending the default theme the main table of that collection is `catalog_product_index_price` instead `catalog_product_entity` or `catalog_product_flat_{current_store}`. Check that: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94963/product-list-attribute-filter-query/94965?noredirect=1#comment127823_94965

Answer (score 0):

I just took the code and transformed it into one single query instead of 2.
The idea is to join left the products table with the table that keeps the relation between simple and configurable, and filter only the products that don't have such a relation:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*'); //or just the attributes you need

$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('link_table' => 'catalog_product_super_link'),
    'link_table.product_id = e.entity_id',
    array('product_id')
);
$collection->getSelect()->where('link_table.product_id IS NULL');
```

now you just need to loop through the collection.

```
foreach ($collection as $product) {
     //do something with $product
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Code

I cannot see any reason why it should not work. Have you tried cleaning all caches?

Both themes' layout XML files reference the same block type, i.e.

**rwd**

```
/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/catalog.xml

<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
```

**base/default**

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml

<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
```

### Product visibility

But maybe it can be solved differently: You can set visibility per product, so you might as well set all configurable and bundle products to Visible in: '`Search`' instead of '`Catalog, Search`'. This can be set in Magento admin area, Catalog > Product Management.